# Can I force a web proxy to use a specific IP address for a hostname?

Tags: dns, ip, proxy, hosts-file

Background: I want to test a site on Akamai's staging network. This usually requires you to find out the IP address of the specific edge hostname and then change your local `/etc/hosts` file so the hostname is associated with the Akamai staging IP.

However, I need to use a proxy to access this specific site. So whatever I put in my local hosts file, the IP address will be looked up by the proxy and not by my local machine, which makes the whole thing pointless.

Is there a workaround for this? I don't have access to the proxy, and even if I had, I wouldn't want to log in there to mess with its hosts file everytime I need to test something on Akamai's staging network.

Also please don't write answers like "change your setup" - I know this is a weird configuration, and it's not the only one. I'm just interested if there is a technical solution to this.

Comment: I have seen that certain clients to the DNS resolution themselves (e.g. using DNSolver HTTPS) and then the proxy only gets `CONNECT <IP address>` instead of `CONNECT example.org`.